# Option Pricing, A Practitioners Guide, Martingale's, Drift Change and Radon-Nikodym

Tags: finance, martingales

[image]

Im slightly confused about this section of the booklet regarding option prices byIain J. Clark.

1) Regarding the part of obtaining a martingale property we require that the last exponential term disappears for Z, why is this? Is this because we dont want the expectation to depend on any previous results before time t, and the interest rates will?
2) Why is that particular drift change required?
3) And im completely lost with Radon-Nikodym.

I realise I am basically struggling with the whole of this question however any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

James

REVISED QUESTION:

Maybe we can go back to the equities one for a simpler argument on how to get the Wd and apply R-N: Please see the photos below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: 1) a martingale requires a zero drift (at least) 2) because you change the variable to remove the dt I.e drift 3) the R-N is a change of measure (in Baxter and rennie) it goes through the binomial model and it is representing the change of probabilities under different processes.

Comment: Ok great thankyou, I now understand why the martingale requires zero drift. If you get a chance can you explain the drift change required in more detail and the radon nikodym derivate? we change which variable in what equation to remove the dt?

Comment: Hi again. Ok a little more detail. To specifically derive the "change in variables" you have to use Ito lemma first on $Z_t$ and use $W_t = \tilde{W}_t -\gamma_t t$ (now we have to remember that $\gamma$ is not generally constant with respect to t) from here you find a $\gamma$ that makes $dZ_t$~$d\tilde{W}_t$. You will also do this for the stock price $S_t$ in the next part. As for R-N what do you need to know? Since the equation given is valid.

Comment: I have edited the original question to produce that one of the equities walkthrough so it should be simpler. Im sure this isnt very difficult im just over complicating things as usual but be great to understand this! Essentially Im wondering why that particular Wt is needed to ensure the R-N derivative holds. Im going through R-N again as we speak, ill write my understandings so far below

Answer (score 0):

Using Ito's lemma we can see the condition for $Z_{t}$ to be martingale in **Q2.7.2** as follows
$$
dZ_{t} = \left(\frac{\partial Z_{t}}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2} Z_{t}}{\partial W_{t}^{2}}\right)dt + \frac{\partial Z_{t}}{\partial W_{t}}dW_{t} \implies \\
dZ_{t} = \left[\left(\mu + r^{f}-r^{d} - \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2} + \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}\right)dt + \sigma dW_{t}\right]Z_{t}
$$
So for $Z_t$ to be martingale the drift term must vanish i.e. coefficient of dt identically zero.
or 
$$
\mu + r^{f}-r^{d} - \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2} + \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2} = 0,
$$
that is,
$$
\mu = r^{d} - r^{f}
$$

For the next bit who to get the "change in variable" we utilise that we can transform a process with 
$$
W^{d}_{t} = \tilde{W_{t}} - \int \gamma_{t}dt
$$

(I can't remember the appropriate name for the above transform) Though you have to satisfy a bunch of conditions, namely that $\gamma_{t}$  must be bounded.

So using Ito on the above we arrive at 
$$
dW^{d}_{t} = dW_{t} - \gamma dt 
$$
Here I have dropped the subscript $t$ for $\gamma$ as the drift is constant wrt $t$.
so 
$$
dS_{t} = \sigma S_{t} dW_{t} + \left(r^{d} - r^{f}\right)S_{t}dt,\\
\,\,\,\,= \sigma S_{t}\left(dW_{t} - \gamma dt \right) + \left(r^{d} - r^{f}\right)S_{t}dt,\\
=\sigma S_{t} dW_{t} + \left(r^{d} - r^{f} - \gamma \sigma\right)S_{t}dt.
$$
Now for $S_t$ to become martingale under this change we require the drift to be zero again.
Therefore
$$
\left(r^{d} - r^{f} - \gamma \sigma\right) = 0,
$$
that is,
$$
\gamma = \frac{r^{d} - r^{f}}{\sigma}
$$
or 
$$
W_{t}^{d} = W_{t} + \frac{r^{f} - r^{d}}{\sigma}t.
$$

Now I may of made a mistake, but this is how i followed through.

**Please note that this is not complete and does not correspond to the Original question result, so highlight where I went wrong and help the OP and I will remove/edit where necessary.**

Comment: Great thank you very much for your assistance on this. I just have a few follow up questions (please bear with me on this!!)
1) I get the same

Comment: ok send me some questions and I will answer if i can.

Comment: Actually I think its all good now it has finally clicked. Thank you for a great explanation. They missed out a bunch of lines in the book im reading. I guess the only question I have is when you implement Itos Lemma on Zt why does the differential of Wt wrt t disappear, i cant see it cancelling with anything.